# Difference between a battery shunt and a watt meter?

Tags: electrical

What's the difference between a battery shunt and a watt meter.

Shunt like a Victron 500A - I understands displays the V/A and SoC.

and something like

[https://www.amazon.com/LoveDeal-Precision-Wattmeter-Real-time-Backlight/dp/B0CC5F16T5/ref=sr_1_13?keywords=watt+meter&qid=1695503853&sr=8-13](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CC5F16T5)

I don't think the second one knows anything about the battery's SoC - is that the only difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Amazon wattmeter is a relatively dumb device. It measures the voltage and current from the battery and uses that information to calculate power and energy usage (by keeping track of time), It does not make any measurements related to the health of the battery. The Victron device makes the same basic measurements (voltage and current from the battery and time) but has a microprocessor to analyze that information using battery wellness algorithms to calculate battery health. This feature (plus the Bluetooth connection) accounts for the large difference in cost of the 2 devices.

Comment: So basically same real-time reporting by both but Victron also displays SoC because of firmware capability. I see it displays a percent charge. So to do that I would assume it needs to know battery type and capacity - something that would have to be input by the user perhaps?? If the battery is being charged and discharged at the same time - can the Victron track that. The unit seems to go between the battery and the load - but I could have another pair to the battery coming from the charger. Thank you both for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

In the generic sense of the term, a battery shunt is a device inserted into a current path. The shunt has a known precise resistance with measuring leads at each end of the shunt. Those leads provide a means to determine the voltage drop across the span. When combined with a measuring device, many types of data can be measured.

The watttmeter you've linked includes an internal shunt. My search discovered what is called a smart battery shunt, as opposed to a generic (un-smart?) one. Some of these products include a display and a means to present the desired data by pushing selector buttons, while others are now available to communicate with a smart phone.

The battery state of charge cannot be determined by either device unless the internal software (firmware) or application monitors the use from a specific start point (full charge) to present-time. If a device purports to provide battery SOC, it must have a battery chemistry reference and a known expected cut-off point.

I have a high-current CycleAnalyst mounted to my electric ride-on lawn mower. It provides amp-hours used from last reset and I use the known amp-hour capacity of my battery as a reference to determine SOC. For lead-acid batteries, one should not go below fifty percent SOC, while lithium batteries can tolerate up to an eighty percent depth of discharge.